# ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 250 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I tried to develop a CNN model to extract feature from vein images but I cant solve the `ValueError` shown.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(48, 64, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen.fit(x_train)

model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=3), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train)/3, epochs=12, verbose=1)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The error trace is as follows:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b07132f37f80> in <module>
     12 datagen.fit(x_train)
     13 
---> 14 model.fit(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=3), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train)/3, epochs=12, verbose=1)
     15 score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
     16 print('Test loss:', score[0])

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    694     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    697             *args, **kwds))
    698 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3063     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3064     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3065         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3066             self._name,
   3067             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:748 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1535 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4687 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\Asus\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, None, None, None) and (None, 5) are incompatible
```

Comment: Still not clear if the error comes from `model.fit()` or from `model.evaluate()`; you sure posted the whole trace?

Comment: Yes, it is the complete error trace.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see from your code, here:

```
model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
```

You should use activation to `softmax` if you use the loss function `categorical cross entropy`. Or, use `binary_cross_entropy` if activation need to be `sigmoid`

Comment: I have change sigmoid to softmax but still pops up the error

Comment: Error is like this : Layer sequential_1 expects 1 inputs, but it received 250 input tensors.

Comment: Seeing the log message, I think there is something wrong with your training data preprocessing step. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I simply resize the images, originally 640x480 to 64x48, append the images to a list and did some data augmentation. I didnt do much on preprocessing..

Comment: Can you reproduce your error with some public data, like mnist or cifar10? It will help others to give you an answer quickly.

Comment: Sorry Im not sure how... Im new to python programming...

Comment: What data are you using? Is it publicly available? If not, can you share some similar data?

Comment: Im using finger vein images collected by my faculty, but it cannot be shared according to faculty rules.. Ive searched online but most of the public datasets requires license agreement to access..

Comment: The shape of x_train is 250, 48, 64, 3. And the error says "it received 250 input tensors". Does it have something to do with x_train?

Comment: Is your batch size 250? Or, you are using 3D data?

Comment: No, my batch size is 128. Im using monochrome images captured using NIR camera.

Comment: The 250 is my input size. Does the layer sequential_1 in the error means the first layer of the network (the Conv2D)?

Comment: According to your model definition, your input image size should be `48, 64, 3`.  What's the format of your image?

Comment: yes the format of the images is 48, 64, 3

Comment: So, is 250 is the number of the samples, the total train set?

Comment: Yes. Pls wait a while ya, I want to make some changes to my code

Comment: I have amended the code. I used datagen.flow to do a real time augmentation, but its having error. Can you please kindly take a look at it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's hard to hell. I suggest you if possible to provide similar types of data - you do not need to provide any big stuff but just a fake similar input. That would be more convenient.