# ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 239 input tensors

Tags: python, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

I am trying to test a simple convolutional layer where the input images (with 1 band= grayscale) are numpy arrays stored in a list and targets are stored in a pandas dataframe. The size of input images is 16x16. The output for the model.fit is an error of "Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 239 input tensors". I also checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720798/valueerror-layer-sequential-expects-1-inputs-but-it-received-250-input-tensors) but still I couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

```
(trainY, testY, trainX, testX) = train_test_split(df, images, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
print (np.shape(trainY),np.shape(testY),np.shape(trainX),np.shape(testX))

result: (239, 1) (60, 1) (239, 16, 16) (60, 16, 16)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(16, 16, 1),name='Layer1'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu',name='layer2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='linear',name='Layer3'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, 
                    validation_split=.2, batch_size=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input expected by the  model as defined in you model architecture is

```
input_shape=(16, 16, 1)
```

So while training you can send a batch of `16X16` single channel (`X1`) images. However your data shape is `(239, 16, 16)`. i.e you have a batch of 239 images of `16X16`. All you have to do is reshape `16X16` to `16X16X1`. Since your data is in numpy array you can do this using `expand_dim`.

```
trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, -1)
```

#### Fixed code

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', 
                        input_shape=(16, 16, 1),name='Layer1'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu',name='layer2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='linear',name='Layer3'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mae'])

trainY = np.random.randint(0,10, (239, 1))
trainX = np.random.randn(239, 16, 16)

trainX = np.expand_dims(trainX, -1)
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10, validation_split=.2, batch_size=4)
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to run the code by your answer. I need to keep trainX and trainY with decimal values. May I know what are the functions of `trainY = np.random.randint(0,10, (239, 1)) and
trainX = np.random.randn(239, 16, 16)`? Are there any conversion of decimal values to integer?

Comment: I guess I should remove `trainY = np.random.randint(0,10, (239, 1)) and trainX = np.random.randn(239, 16, 16)`. Am I right?

Comment: yes `randn` was to generate synthetic data, you will have to remove it. Do expad_dim on `trainX` and `testX`